# How to create a DataFrame column based on multiple columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a DataFrame that looks like this

| Name | Result_cat_1 | Result1 | Result_cat_2 | Result_2 | Result_cat_3 | Result_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | Rock | 12 plays | Paper | 4 plays | Scissors | 45 plays |
| John | Paper | 8 plays | Scissors | 15 plays | Rock | 76 plays |
| Ronald | Scissors | 6 plays | Rock | 3 plays | Paper | 23 plays |

The end result should be like this:

| Name | Rock | Paper | Scissors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 12 plays | 4 plays | 45 plays |
| John | 76 plays | 8 plays | 15 plays |
| Ronald | 3 plays | 23 plays | 6 plays |

I've tried

```
df['Rock'] = df[Result1].where(df[Result_cat_1] == 'Rock')
df['Rock'] = df[Result2].where(df[Result_cat_2] == 'Rock')
df['Rock'] = df[Result3].where(df[Result_cat_3] == 'Rock')
```

but the column contains only the `df[Result_cat_3]` overwriting the previous 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `stack` the "Results_cat" columns and "Results" columns separately; build a DataFrame with the stacked Series; then `pivot`:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
out = (df.filter(like='Result_cat')
       .stack()
       .droplevel(1)
       .reset_index(name='result')
       .assign(play=df[['Result1', 'Result_2', 'Result_3']]
               .stack().to_numpy())
       .pivot('Name', 'result', 'play')
       .rename_axis(index=[None], columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
           Paper      Rock  Scissors
Andrew   4 plays  12 plays  45 plays
John     8 plays  76 plays  15 plays
Ronald  23 plays   3 plays   6 plays
```